# JDK 11 migration issue from JDK8, Illegal reflective access by com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.util.MyClassLoader

Tags: spring-boot, migration, jhipster, java-11

I have successfully migrated my spring boot project(running in prod env) from JDK8 to JDK11.
I can build, test, package, install, deploy and everything.

After starting the project from my IDE, I have the following warnings in my log, which doesn't stop from building  and running my application.

Please advise on this.

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
***`WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.util.MyClassLoader (file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-afterburner/2.11.0/jackson-module-afterburner-2.11.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String)`***
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.util.MyClassLoader
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: And how is dumping a warning asking a question? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question to be a proper question.

Comment: I am sorry about that, This is my first question posting here

Comment: @M.Deinum Mahesh did ask for advice to solve that warning. Please don't bully the new joiners. This community has been toxic that way.

Answer (score 6):

We have removed afterburner completely in the latest releases as it didn't provide significant improvements (anymore) and is not compatible with java 9+. So remove it completely I would say.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out.